# Undefined Post with express.js and node 0.10.29

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, express

I'm trying to post json to an express server and getting undefined on req.body.name.

the configuration look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
   app.use(express.json());
   app.use(express.urlencoded());
   app.use(express.methodOverride());
   app.use(app.router);
});
```

The routes look like this:

```
module.exports.start = function(){

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
      console.log("params: " + req.params);
      res.send("got it");
  });

  app.post('/test', function(req, res){
      console.log("Post test: " + req.body.name);//this is undefined
      res.send(req.body);
  });

  app.set('port', process.env.Port || 3000);
  app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
          console.log("listening on port: " + app.get('port'));
      }
      console.log("listening on port: " + app.get('port'));
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need a body parser

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

which is now, with the version 4.* of *expressjs*, [a separate module.](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: Isin't the express.json() enough?

Comment: Hm, it should be enough if the content-type is established as "application/json"

Comment: yes, I'm setting the content-type to application/json, but the problem persists.

Comment: That's strange then. Could you provide a bit more detail, perhaps  request headers?

Comment: I'm sending {"name": "test"}. Another thing is that this works on one of my laptops and not on the rest. The difference between the two is that I've installed node today on the ones that don't work. I've tried downgrading to an earlier version with no luck.

Comment: If you have the time, you can try out the project : https://github.com/sfabriece/nodeTest